# Why doesn't my IF Statement work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Can someone explain why my if statement doesn't work in the displayStorageSizeToConvert() function? Please and thank you!

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
var kbButton = document.getElementById("k");
var mbButton = document.getElementById("mbButton");
var KilobyteDisplay = document.getElementById('KilobyteDisplay');
var megabyteDisplay = document.getElementById('megabyteDisplay');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

function displayStorageSizeToConvert() {
    if (kbButton.clicked === true) {    
        return convertFrom.innerHTML = "KB";    
    }
    else {
        return convertFrom.innerHTML = "MB";
    }
}


    function convertStorageSizeFrom() {
    if(convertFrom.value === "KB") {
        KilobyteDisplay.innerHTML = userInput.value + " KB";
        megabyteDisplay.innerHTML = userInput.value / 1000 + " MB";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you invoking displayStorageSizeToConvert?

Comment: Not enough info. You don't show how the function is invoked, how the button gets its `clicked` property, or what sort of data `clicked` contains.

Comment: try using `kbButton.clicked == true` instead of a strong type check.

Comment: @jithil that's bad advice. OP should know at least what type of value he's expecting. And if `kbButton.clicked` ain't of that type he has another problem (potential bug). imo, if JS would abandon `==` the world would only loose buggy code.

Comment: Okay. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're invoking your function anywhere.

Also, you should attach this function to a click handler:

```js
function displayInKB() {
    convertFrom.innerHTML = "KB";    
}

function displayInMb() {
    convertFrom.innerHTML = "MB";    
}

kbButton.addEventListener('click', displayInKb);
mbButton.addEventListener('click', displayInMb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not currently ever calling/triggering displayStorageSizeToConvert().

I think you are wanting to create a listener. You can add it like this:

```
kbButton.addEventListener('click', () => convertForm.innerHTML = "KB")
```